# Create image bloburl from canvas.toDataURL()

Tags: canvas, base64, tcpdf, pdf.js, bloburls

I have pdf output as base64 string. I want to create bloburl for each pages from this format. So, I create bloburl for whole pdf using this base64 string. Then, I use pdfjs and display first page in newly created canvas. Now, I try to get displayed picture as image blob.

1. I am having error (`Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string
   to be decoded is not correctly encoded.`) when create blob  by
   execute code
   `b64toBlob(pag1.toDataURL('image/png',1.0),'image/png')`.
2. Then I tried
   `b64toBlob(window.btoa(pag1.toDataURL('image/png',1.0)),'image/png')`
   It display empty image from url created for this blob.
3. `var b2 =pag1.toBlob(function(blob) {}, 'image/png')` output undefined.

   ```
   <?php
   ob_start();
   require_once('plugin/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
   $pdf    =new TCPDF();
   $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
   $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
   $pdf->AddPage();
   $html_p1='Text messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messages, typically consisting of alphabetic and numeric characters, between two or more users of mobile devices, desktops/laptops, or other type of compatible computer. Text messages may be sent over a cellular network, or may also be sent via an Internet connection';
   $pdf->writeHTML($html_p1, true, 0, true, 0);
   $pdf->AddPage();
   $html_p2='A telephone call is a connection over a telephone network between the called party and the calling party.';
   $pdf->writeHTML($html_p2, true, 0, true, 0);
   $base64PdfString = $pdf->Output('', 'E');
   $base64PdfArray = explode("\r\n", $base64PdfString);
   $base64 = '';
   for($i = 5; $i < count($base64PdfArray); $i++) 
   {
       $base64 .= $base64PdfArray[$i];
   }
    ?>

    <!doctype html>
     <head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width = 1050, user-scalable = no" />
       <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/turnjs4/extras/jquery.min.1.7.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/turnjs4/extras/modernizr.2.5.3.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/pdfjs_ex/pdf.js"></script>    
      <script>     

      const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512) =>
     {
       const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
       const byteArrays = [];

       for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize)
       {
           const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
           const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
           for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++)
           {
               byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
           }
           const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
           byteArrays.push(byteArray);
       }

       const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
       return blob;
   }



   $( document ).ready(function() {

       const contentType   ='application/pdf';
       const b64Data       ='<?php echo $base64;?>';
       const blob          =b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType);

       const blobUrl       =URL.createObjectURL(blob);


       PDFJS.getDocument({ url: blobUrl }).then(function(pdf_doc) 
       {
               __PDF_DOC = pdf_doc;
               __TOTAL_PAGES = __PDF_DOC.numPages;
               var div_container = document.querySelector('#flipbook');
               pdf_doc.getPage(1).then(function(page) 
               {
                   var scale = 1;
                   var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

                   // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
                  var pag1 = document.createElement('canvas');
                   pag1.id ='Pg_1';
                   var context1 = pag1.getContext('2d');
                   pag1.height = viewport.height;
                   pag1.width = viewport.width;
                   var renderContext = 
                  {
                       canvasContext: context1,
                       viewport: viewport
                   };
                page.render(renderContext).then(function()
               {
                   div_container.appendChild(pag1);
                   var dataUrl =pag1.toDataURL(); 

               //const b   =b64toBlob(dataUrl,'image/png');
               //const b   =b64toBlob(window.btoa(dataUrl),'image/png');
               //const burl =URL.createObjectURL(b); 
               //console.log(b);

               //var b2 =pag1.toBlob(function(blob) {}, 'image/png');

           var element                     = document.createElement("div");
           element.style.backgroundImage   = "url(" + dataUrl + ")";
           div_container.appendChild(element);
            $("#Pg_1").remove(); 

             });
               });

       })

   })
    </script>
   </head>

   <body>
    <!--<div id="magazine">
       <canvas id="pdf"></canvas>
    </div>-->

    <div class="flipbook-viewport">
     <div class="container">
         <div class="flipbook" id="flipbook">
             <!--<canvas id="pdf"></canvas>-->
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>


   <script type="text/javascript">

   function loadApp() {

   // Create the flipbook

   $('.flipbook').turn({
           // Width

           width:922,

           // Height

           height:600,

           // Elevation

           elevation: 50,

           // Enable gradients

           gradients: true,

           // Auto center this flipbook

           autoCenter: true

   });
    }

     // Load the HTML4 version if there's not CSS transform

      yepnope({
       test : Modernizr.csstransforms,
       yep: ['plugin/turnjs4/lib/turn.js'],
       nope: ['plugin/turnjs4/lib/turn.html4.min.js'],
       both: ['plugin/turnjs4/samples/basic/css/basic.css'],
       complete: loadApp
      });

     </script>

    </body>
   ```

When I execute `console.log(dataURL)`, It start with `data:image/png;base64`. So, I thought It has been base-64 encoded. But, error saying not  correctly decoded. Why is it so and `how to create imagebloburl from canvas displaying pdf page`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This able to create image bloburl . But show undefined when access burl variable out of the function.

```
  pag1.toBlob(function(blob) 
    {
       var burl =URL.createObjectURL(blob); 

    }, 'image/png');
```

Looking forward for better solution.